# How to change default path for photo booth?

Tags: macos, applications, path, photo-booth

By default, photo booth save videos in

```
/Users/UserName/Pictures/Photo\ Booth\ Library
```

Is there a way to change this default path?

I am on OSX 10.11.5

Comment: Have you try by moving the `Booth Library` in another location?

Comment: No, I haven't tried that....and it works! Thanks! You can make an answer out of your comment. These Apple Applications are pretty weird in how they work. I would have expected an error message when moving this folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I report here as an answer my comment above.

---

You can move the `Photo Booth Library` to the location you prefer, this procedure should automatically change the path of the *Photo Booth* application.

Note that the library is a package that keeps all the photos and the content of the application, if you delete it you will lose all your pics and data.

Comment: Doesn't work if you try to move it to an external drive though... Still trying to figure out how to do that.